# How to make Mathematica solve an equation in an analytic class?

Tags: differential-equations

Here is my small code:

```
DSolve[{x D[K[x, y, u, v], u] - u D[K[x, y, u, v], x] + 
        y D[K[x, y, u, v], v] - v D[K[x, y, u, v], y] == 0}, K, {x, y, u, 
      v}]
```

As a result I have:

```
{{K -> Function[{x, y, u, v}, 
    C[1][1/2 (u^2 + x^2), 
     v Sqrt[(u^2 + x^2)/u^2] - (v x^2 Sqrt[(u^2 + x^2)/u^2])/(
      u^2 + x^2) + (u x Sqrt[(u^2 + x^2)/u^2] y)/(
      u^2 + x^2), -((u v x Sqrt[(u^2 + x^2)/u^2])/(u^2 + x^2)) + 
      Sqrt[(u^2 + x^2)/u^2] y - (x^2 Sqrt[(u^2 + x^2)/u^2] y)/(
      u^2 + x^2)]]}}
```

which seems strange. This equation is just:

```
u K_x - x K_u + v K_y - y K_v = 0
```

symmetrical with respect to couples (x,u) and (v,y).
I am waiting for the answer -- any function F(x^2+u^2, y^2+v^2). How to obtain it ? What if going on?

And the second question, can I force in DSolve for Mathematica to search solutions that converge in every point ? In order not to have singularities in 0.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the first question, *Mathematica* is returning an arbitrary function of `x, y, u, v` called `C[1]`; the arguments of the solution are:

```
sol = K /. First@DSolve[{x D[K[x, y, u, v], u] - u D[K[x, y, u, v], x] + 
       y D[K[x, y, u, v], v] - v D[K[x, y, u, v], y] == 0}, K, {x, y, u, v}];

args = ReplacePart[sol[[2]], 0 -> List];

FullSimplify[args, Assumptions -> {x ∈ Reals, y ∈ Reals, u ∈ Reals, v ∈ Reals}]
(* {1/2 (u^2 + x^2), ((u v + x y) Sign[u])/Sqrt[u^2 + x^2], ((-v x + u y) Sign[u])/Sqrt[u^2 + x^2]} *)
```

So the solution depends on `u^2 + x^2` and the combinations `u v + x y`, `-v x + u y`.

Comment: Thank you ! So actually it was a right answer in a very strange form !